# No "Terminal Services" branch in "Group Policy Object Editor"

Tags: windows, group-policy, terminal

We have several identical several servers in a hosting company.
They run Windows 2003 R2 Std SP2 64bit. The servers are not in a domain.
We have recently received a new server with the same configuration and hardware.
However, the new server is different in some way. When we run "gpedit.msc /s" there are much less options in the tree than the other servers. Specifically we are missing the configuration of "Terminal Services".
Many other items are missing under "Administrative templates" and "Windows components".

Screenshot of correct server: (can't post link due to SF policy)

Screenshot of new server: http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/572/gpowindowscomponentstp5.png

What should we try?

Thanks,
Arik.

Comment: link to screenshot of correct server: http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/3532/gpowindowscomponentsoth.png

Answer (score 1):

The IT technician solved the issue by renaming C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\Adm to something else which caused the folder to be re-created with correct content (run gpedit).
The old files seem to be different that the files that cause the branches to appear.

Hope it helps somebody.